# how to find lexicographic string based on specified ranking

Tags: javascript, logic

Consider all the strings of length 6 composed of capital Latin letters (A - Z), sorted in lexicographic order. The string AAAAAA is the first. The string AAAAAZ is the 26th . The 27th is AAAABA. The hint to this problem is the Nth string where N is the number of primes less than 2^ 30 − M . M is a permutation of 123456789, and we won’t tell you which one it is, but we will give you the following constraints to reduce the space of possibilities:

1. M is divisible by 567.
2. M starts with 2, ends with 4, and the middle digit is 8.

I managed to find M and the Nth, but I am not able to find a solution on how to find the right string based on the ranking. Please note that I found 9 possibilities on the ranking (Nth) which are:

- 43973488
- 43929860
- 41992802
- 41914646
- 41831591
- 41232030
- 41066565
- 40861259
- 40167328

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to find all 9 possible string ?

Comment: Yes am supposed to find all 9 possible strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert the numbers to base 26 , and match each digit to the related chars

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
function convertToBase26Strings(number) {
  number = number - 1 ;
  var res = ""
  while(number >= chars.length ) {
    var i = number % chars.length ;
    number = Math.floor(number / chars.length)
    res += chars[i];
  }
  res += chars[number];
  return res.split("").reverse().join("").padStart(6 , "A");
}
console.log(convertToBase26Strings(1));
console.log(convertToBase26Strings(26));
console.log(convertToBase26Strings(27));
```